# Stmt->errorCode not working

Tags: php, pdo

im having a little problem getting the if($stmt->errorCode() == 0) { in my code to work. If i do a search with a ticket number that is in the database it will show it but if i do a search with a random number that's not in the database it will not show the error message no ticket found.

```
     <?php
require("db.php");
$error_message="";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(empty($_POST['term']))
{
$error_message="Please enter a Ticket Number.";
}
else
{
$query = "SELECT department, subject, message FROM supporttickets Where ticketnumber LIKE :term";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':term' => $_POST['term']));

if($stmt->errorCode() == 0) {
while (list($department,$subject,$message) = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
echo htmlentities($department);
}
}else{

$error_message="no ticket found.";
 }

 }
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not actually `echo`ing the output. This just assigns a variable:

```
$error_message="no ticket found.";
```

What you want is:

```
$error_message="no ticket found.";
echo $error_message;
```

Or maybe just:

```
echo "no ticket found.";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need no error codes here

```
<?php
require("db.php");
$data = array();
if(!empty($_GET['term']))
{
    $query = "SELECT department, subject, message FROM supporttickets 
              WHERE ticketnumber = ?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array($_GET['term']));
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
}

foreach ($data as $row)
{
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['department']);
}
if (!$data)
{
    echo "Please enter valid Ticket Number.";
}
```

A couple of mistakes also corrected.

Comment: hi thanks for the help guys, but i'm getting this in return even if the ticket number is in the database (Please enter valid Ticket Number.)

Comment: you should use GET method in your form for the search, not POST